# Scheme programming exercise

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm new in scheme and i'm trying to solve a proposed exercise. I appreciate your ideas about how to solve it, this is the exercise:

Write a procedure "filteredmap" that takes 2 functions and that applies the first function when a predicate (also to be passed as an argument) returns #t and that applies the second function when the predicate yields #f.

Example:

```
> (filteredmap even? (lambda (x) (+ x 1))
                     (lambda (x) (* x 2))
                     (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(2 3 6 5 10 7 14 9 18 11)

> (filteredmap even? (lambda (x) "yes, yes, even!")
                     (lambda (x) "oh no!")
                     (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))

  ("oh no!" "yes, yes, even!" "oh no!" "yes, yes, even!" "oh no!" "yes, yes,
  even!" "oh no!" "yes, yes, even!" "oh no!" "yes, yes, even!")
```

Any idea how to implement it?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: `filteredmap p g h = map ([x] => p x ? g x : h x)`.

Comment: You really should try to solve your homework on your own, before asking someone else to do it for you. That's not what Stack Overflow is for, and you're only cheating yourself instead of learning.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it by using `map`. Think if you had the three functions like `odd?`, `add1`, and `sub1` and wanted to use `map` instead to achieve the same result, how would you construct the lambda you pass as the first argument?

When you know that you can use that to make `filteredmap` that just use `map` the same way but by using the variables you have named the 3 parts instead. Easy peasy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a high-order-function such as a fold-right, you can use a map using lambdas, or you use an iterative solution getting the answer in a list which is "backwards" by reading the first element of the list and calling `cons` with the correct map and the accumulator as the cdr, so you'll need to call `reverse` at the end. Here is my solution:

```
(define (filteredmap predicate fun1 fun2 items)
    (define (fm-iter pred f1 f2 lst acc)
        (cond ((null? lst) acc)
              ((pred (car lst)) (fm-iter pred f1 f2 (cdr lst) (cons (f1 (car lst)) acc)))
              (else (fm-iter pred f1 f2 (cdr lst) (cons (f2 (car lst)) acc)))))
    (reverse (fm-iter predicate fun1 fun2 items '() )))
```